# Algorithm for searching missing letters

Tags: trie

So, I have to search for words which have some missing letters(used in a crossword) and also have to maintain a list of the possible words for the remaining spaces.

Now my question is that I have googled that burst-trie if the fastest algorithm for searching.
But if I code this in trie and how hard it would be for me to move to burst-trie.??

Bear with me if something you didn't get you can comment to clarify any point.

Answer (score 1):

First a disclaimer, I have not written a burst-trie. But, reading your question I found the initial paper that proposed the burst-trie, [Burst Tries: A Fast, Ecient Data Structure for
String Keys](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf), and it sounds straight forward. I have written several trie databases and numerous accessory functions.

From what I read it sounds like you write the trie following the standard approach and simply add a bst option to your struct and use that for the last sequence of char. Then add a 'burst' function to your trie class and at your setting, 'burst' the bst into a new level of trie struct and continue with a bst suffix tree.

So, I think the answer to your question is Yes, it is easy to convert your trie to a burst trie.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite simple to turn a trie into a burst trie as long as you have the right layers of abstraction. There's a [Scala implementation](https://github.com/nbauernfeind/scala-burst-trie) of that burst trie paper (that mixes in some ideas from GWT's trie implementation) that is really efficient space-wise (and the space constraint is the most obvious when dealing with a trie).

If you want to build your own, take a look at that implementation for guidance. It is a little generic so that it can be used in different ways; but it should work for your use case if you're on the JVM and don't mind pulling in the scala library.